Setting a higher than supported monitor resolution (X11 / Gnome / Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
I'm mix and matching a 1440P display with a 1080P display, and I'm trying to get the 1080P display to "behave" like the 1440P display, in terms of windows size and mouse movement. Both are 32 inch displays.
In my Windows 11 Dual boot, I can achieve this by using AMD's virtual super resolution feature, which allows me to set a 1440P virtual resolution on my 1080P display. (I'm using an RX 6700XT GPU and an AMD CPU with IGPU)
I've looked into similar solution on Ubuntu but none seems to work. I have tried to use xrandr to add a new mode:
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440R"  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync 
This is generated using cvt with --reduced option. However, after adding the mode to my monitor and settings the resolution to 1440P:
xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-1-1 2560x1440R
The monitor goes into black screen and displays an "out of range" error.
I've also tried using scaling:
xrandr --output HDMI-A-1-1 --auto --scale 1.25x1.25
But the monitor has overflown. Only part of the monitor is usable. (Sounds weird to describe, but only the "1920 x 1080" part of the full "2560x1440" resolution is usable)
I've also tried to modify the ~/.config/monitor.xml file and change the scale to 0.75, but the file resets everytime I reboot.
I am running out of ideas. If there is a method available in Wayland I'm willing to switch.
